# Docker MariaDB instance not starting after update

Tags: ubuntu, docker, mariadb

I am getting the following errors from my log. I only updated the image and restarted. Could a recent change in the image have caused these errors? My host has plenty of space, so I’m not sure why I’m getting the out of space error for `./ibtmp1`

The issue occurs when updating from mariadb 10.2.9 to 10.2.10.

```
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191215482624 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:32 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:33 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:33 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:33 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:33 140191958161280 [ERROR] InnoDB: preallocating 12582912 bytes for file ./ibtmp1 failed with error 22
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:33 140191958161280 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:33 140191958161280 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:33 140191958161280 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:38 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:38 140191958161280 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:38 140191958161280 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:38 140191958161280 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:38 140191958161280 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:38 140191958161280 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
db_1           | 2017-11-07 21:11:38 140191958161280 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I also asked the question here: https://forums.docker.com/t/mariadb-not-starting-after-update/40978

Comment: Error 22 (the first one that shows up) means ERROR_BAD_COMMAND or device error. Does the respective disk work fine? Full?

Comment: Yes, the disk if fine and I have plenty of memory.

Comment: Downgrading to 10.2.9 fixes the issue for me. I'm thinking this is a bug with 10.2.10 in either MariaDB or the MariaDB docker image. I created an issue here: https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/138

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on docker for Windows. Suddenly the container failed to start with an out of space error.

At first I thought, that I **do** have enough space on the host system, but actually 
the **virtual hard disk** (created by the docker engine) which is used in the background, ran out of space.

Is solved the problem by:

`docker-compose down`

`docker system prune`

`docker-compose up`

Comment: Hi @alex this did not work. I have the same error but these three commends did not save me. :-(